# Arduino, changing value in matrix

Tags: matrix, arduino, packet, arduino-c++

I have would like to write a script for Arduino that requires the program to reverse the value of a single entry in a matrix or packet from 0 to 1, or vice versa,depending on the previous entry. My attempts so far have failed miserably. This would be part of an "if" statement.

```
`struct Packet`        

{



  byte address[8];        
  byte command_1[8];        
  byte XOR[8];        
}        
 train =          {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},      // address        
                  {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // command_1         
                  {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}  // error check. Calculated later        
};
```

Comment: I tried:   if (train[1][3] == 1) {
    train[1][3] = 0;
      }
      else {
    train[1][3] = 1;
      }

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a 2dimensional array, but a single Packet, consisting of three arrays, which --by chance-- have the same size.

As you only want to invert one of the elements of the XOR array, I assume `bool` is a more suitable data type.

```
struct Packet {
      byte address[8];        
      byte command_1[8];        
      bool XOR[8];        
    } 
 train = { {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, // address        
           {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // command_1         
           {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}  // error check. Calculated later        
};  

void invertX(Packet& t, byte b) {
// invert a single XOR entry in the packet
   t.XOR[b] = ! t.XOR[b];
}

void setup() {
// Sample usage
   invertX(train,1);
}
```

If this is not your intention, you should edit your question.

I could imagine that you instead have an array of 8 Packet objects, each consisting of 3 elements {byte address; byte command; byte XOR };